# Setting slider to max value

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, slider, uislider

I am creating an application of light in which i am displaying image of light. On light i am changing the brightness of light. If i set my slider minimum and maximum value as

```
slider.minimumValue = -100;
slider.maximumValue = 100;
```

then slider shows marker at 0th position which displays as in center.But now my slider initial and maximum value has been changed as

```
slider.minimumValue = 0;
slider.maximumValue = 100;
```

I want my slider marker should be initially at 100th position of slider i.e. on the top position of slider.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: slider values range from 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
[slider setValue:100.0f animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the slider value

```
[slider setValue:100.0f];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  setting the value of slider to max

```
[slider setValue:100.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
slider.value = 100.0f;
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting value of slider:

initialization slider:

slider.value = 5.0;

minimum value:

slider.minimumValue = 0.0;

maximum value:

slider.maximumValue = 100.0;